# Ubunut systemcontrol service run Qt app as root

Tags: linux, systemd

Hi I need to run a Qt app as root using a service on startup

Here is the systemctrl script

```
[Unit]
Description=QtApp

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /AppDir/QtApp --no-sandbox
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I restart the service app is quieting. What could be the reason.

Comment: Does the app need X11? (I.e. is it graphical?)

Comment: Yes it's GUI App

Comment: Then why in the world is it a service, and a privileged one at that?

Comment: Actually, I have a server application created in Qt with GUI , and it need to run every time and need to start when system boot, and also the app need to write some files on root file system. That's why I have to run it as root using service.

Comment: Well... that's going to be difficult then. Either your app can only start upon login, and be restarted on logout – or it needs its own dedicated Xserver, completely separate from graphical desktops. This is such poor design that I can't come up with a reliably working answer.